# Finding a missing match in two columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I got:

```
a <- c('A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D')
b <- c(1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2)
frame1 <- data.frame(a,b)
```

And now I want to know which string in column 'a' got no number matching '1' in column 'b'.
In this case it would be 'C'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R option -

```
with(frame1, setdiff(unique(a), a[b == 1]))
#[1] "C"
```

Extract `a` values where `b = 1` and use `setdiff` to return the `a` values not in them.

Answer (score 1):

### base R

```r
frame1[ave(frame1$b, frame1$a, FUN = function(z) !1 %in% z) > 0,]
#   a b
# 5 C 2
# 6 C 3
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
frame1 %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  filter(!1 %in% b)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
# # Groups:   a [1]
#   a         b
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 C         2
# 2 C         3
```

Comment: Emphasis on *summarize* by group, but I've unduped it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(frame1)[, .SD[!any(b %in% 1)], a]
   a b
1: C 2
2: C 3
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
unique(subset(frame1, !a %in% a[b == 1])$a)
[1] "C"
```